# Does not log in to the account through the socialaccount in Django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Does not log in to the account through the socialaccount, although the message appears 'Successfully signed in as ' ({% if user.is_authenticated %} is False, user is AnonymousUser). Everything is configured according to the instructions in the documentation. Simple accounts (via login and password) are logged in ({% if user.is_authenticated %} is True).

I've tried different providers, different ways to add keys, and used settings that could have an impact. But nothing helped.

Please help me understand how to set up allauth so that logging in only through the social account is carried out.